# how to open solution file that create from Visual Studio 2019 to different computer that use Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

how to open solution file that create from Visual Studio 2019 to different computer that use Visual Studio 2017 ? my solution file is C# winform application , i try to copy it from vs19 to vs17 but when i open the solution file it load blank ? anyone know the how to make it work ?

Comment: Upgrade to VS2019.  Seriously, or just import the .CS files into a new 2017 project.

Comment: @Trey that machine is my school machine so i can't do anything.

Comment: Make a new project and put all your files into it

Answer (score 1):

If you create a solution in VS2017 it will round trip (assuming you don't use VS2019 only functionality).

(I am currently using VS2019 with a solution where about half the team, and some of our tooling is VS2017 only.)

Comment: can i get more detail , i'm confused

Comment: VS2017 and VS2019 can use the same solution and projects if 1. the solution is created in VS2017, and 2. all the project types and things included in those projects are supported in both